# Spark time in parallel execution in Spark for API call

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am doing this below thing in my 8gigs of laptop and running code in Intellij. I am calling 3 apis in parallel with `map` function and `scalaj`library and calculating time to call each api as follows :

```
val urls = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(Seq("url1", "url2", "url3"))
//for each API call,execute them in different executor and collate data 
val actual_data = urls.map(x => spark.time(HTTPRequestParallel.ds(x)))
```

When `spark.time` is executed,i have expected 3 sets of time but it gives me 6 sets of time

```
Time taken: 14945 ms
Time taken: 21773 ms
Time taken: 22446 ms
Time taken: 6438 ms
Time taken: 6877 ms
Time taken: 7107 ms
```

What am i missing here and is it really parallel calls to api in nature?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually that piece of code alone won't execute any `spark.time` at all, the map function is lazy so it won't be executed until you perform an action on the `RDD`. You should also consider that if you don't persist your transformed `RDD` it will re-compute all transformations for every action. What this mean is that if you are doing something like this:

```
val urls = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(Seq("url1", "url2", "url3"))
//for each API call,execute them in different executor and collate data 
val actual_data = urls.map(x => spark.time(HTTPRequestParallel.ds(x))) 
val c = actual_data.count()
actual_data.collect()
```

There will be 6 executions of what is defined inside the `map` (two for each element in the `RDD`, first one for the `count` and  the second for the `collect`). To avoid this re-computation you can cache or persist the `RDD` as follows

```
val urls = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(Seq("url1", "url2", "url3"))
//for each API call,execute them in different executor and collate data 
val actual_data = urls.map(x => spark.time(HTTPRequestParallel.ds(x))).cache() 
val c = actual_data.count()
actual_data.collect()
```

In this second example you will only see 3 logs instead of 6

Comment: these three will be the time taken for each api call or something more is added in it?

Comment: it should be the time taken to execute the containing block, in this case your code seems to be executing an http call asynchronously, so it won't print the time of the http call but the time it takes to initialize the task that will perform the http call

Comment: Actually i am quite novice,where i can see this task time?

Comment: what library are you sing for your Http calls? I don't know what `HTTPRequestParallel` is... looking to the printed times it looks like it is not actually a asynchronous call so the printed time is the time that took each http call

Comment: sorry, I am not sure what is your question, I think the original question was solved, right?

Comment: Actually as you showed that time is increasing linearly so i am also not quite sure these are happening in parallel.that question is left unanswered.can you help me regarding it?

Comment: spark is executing in parallel all that is inside the map, the parallelism level will be limited by the number of cores available to spark and the number of partitions in the RDD (whatever is less)